# How do I make copies of an array using a void function?

Tags: c, function, void

This is a segment of a simple codebreaker game.  In this piece, the program is meant to compare the hidelist and the guess to find "imperfect matches", as in matches that have the correct number, but in the wrong place.  For example if the hide list was:

12321

and my guess was:

13222

It should say I got 2 perfect matches, and 2 imperfect matches.  I'm really struggling in how I can get my nested loop to "ignore" already discovered imperfect matches or perfect matches (as those are computed in a different function).  I understand I need to create copies of the arrays, but I don't know how to do that using the functions provided.  Please help, I'm really lost.

```
int ImperfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length) {
    int i, j;
    int imperfectsum;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < length; j++){
            if(hidelist[i] == guess[j]){

                }
            }
        }
return imperfectsum;
}

void copyArray(int dest[], int source[], int length) {

return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can assume `dest` is allocated with enough memory to hold `source` for `length` integers, then all you need to do is call [memcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html).

```
memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(*dest) * length);
```

If `dest` and `source` can overlap, then you cannot use `memcpy`. Instead, you would use [memmove](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) if you want a standard function (which means the code should compile on all platforms whose compiler adheres to the standard).

```
memmove(dest, source, sizeof(*dest) * length);
```

If `dest` is not allocated, then you would have to modify your function to return the address of the destination or modify your function's arguments to pass the address of the address of the destination array (i.e., define dest as `int **dest`) and then use [malloc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/free.3.html) to assign `*dest` a value.

```
int * copyArray(int source[], int length) {
    int * dest = malloc(sizeof(*dest) * length);
    if (dest == NULL)
        return NULL;
    memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(*dest) * length); // no overlap possible
    return dest;
}
```

And, as noted by Eric (and others many times), if you use `sizeof(*dest)` instead of `sizeof(int)`, then you won't have to modify the `sizeof` expression in the event that `copyArray`'s prototype changes.

Comment: `bcopy` is not C standard. Use `memmove`. Also `length * sizeof *dest` is preferable to `sizeof(int) * length` since it will automatically adapt if the parameter type changes.

Comment: Good explanation of the limits of `memcpy()` and the use of `memmove()`.